# How do I get Celery to return a json object instead of bytea?

Tags: python, json, postgresql, celery

This is my first time working with Celery in Python 3. To get my feet wet, I'm returning a string "this was a hello task" as a result from a worker and storing this is a Postgres database. When I access the result from my database it's in the form of a memoryview in Python and the database itself has a the result column of celery_taskmeta as the datatype bytea (this is also what Celery sends to the database as well).

This is my celery config:

```
import os

broker_url = os.environ.get('RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_TX_URL')
worker_concurrency = 3
result_backend = 'db+postgres://...'
task_serializer = 'json'
result_serializer = 'json'
accept_content = ['json']
```

Why am I not getting a json result stored in my database? Also, I cannot decode the bytea to json or utf-8 text, i get this error:

here's what it looks like in bytes: `b'\x80\x04\x95\x1b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x8c\x17"this was a hello task"\x94.'`

command: `json.loads(t.tobytes())`

result: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 0):

you need to convert byte data to unicode

```
t.decode("utf-8")
```

Comment: i tried this but i get the same error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode

you can use 2nd parameter to suppress error like

  `t.decode("utf-8", errors="ignore")`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load it with pickle.

```
import pickle

pickle.loads(t, encoding='utf-8')
```

Struggling with this myself, trying to get Celery to store results in the DB JSON-serialized instead of pickled.